# How to write web-service response to file using camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to GET the response from a REST webservice hosted at `http://localhost:8089/mock/success` and write the response to a file using `Camel`. Here's the route I've written in java for the same-

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("http://localhost:8089/mock/success")
    .to("file://D:/tmp/restoutput");
```

Here's how I'm invoking this route-

```
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
RouteBuilder routebuilder = new RestToFileRoute();
System.out.println("invokeRestToFileRoute() started.");
try {
    ctx.addRoutes(routebuilder);
    ctx.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    ctx.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't get any exceptions but nothing is added to the file. I'm fairly new to Camel so I'm not able to guess the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Using the timer based on suggestions, I'm getting null pointer exception while writing to file. Here's the modified code-

```
from("timer://simpleTimer?repeatCount=1")
    .to("http://localhost:8089/mock/success")
    .process(exchange -> {System.out.println("Message: " + exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class));}) // Output: "Message: null"
    .to("file://D:/tmp/restoutput");
```

Comment: Like @claus mentions, how is your route supposed to be triggered? direct-start is just an in-memory queue. Something needs to be put on it. For simplicity you can just pick up a file, discard it in the route and continue. Or use a timer.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: I'm  not able to use the timer. As for `direct:start`, I misinterpreted the documentation.

Comment: Add log statements after your first .to() and see what the body and headers contain before you write it to file. What do you mean the timer does not work? It doesn't get triggered?

Comment: I think the web service is not being called as the response is being printed as `null`. I have added this code in between-
`.process(exchange -> {System.out.println("Message: " + exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class));})`

Comment: It should be `exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class))` . You don't need `exchange.getOut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either send a message to the direct endpoint, or if you just want to call that endpoint one time, you can use the timer and set its `repeatCount=1` to run once only: http://camel.apache.org/timer

To call the direct endpoint you can use `ProducerTemplate`. Look/search the Camel documentation some more for examples.

Comment: I'm able to get the response using `ProducerTemplate`. But I'm still unable to use the timer. I'm adding the code. Can you please look what's wrong?

Comment: I dont recommend a route if you just want to call a http and save to file. Just use ProducerTemplate to call the HTTP and do the same to store the file. You can just send the body from the HTTP response as the body to the file endpoint with the producer template

Comment: I was so naive earlier that I didn't understand what you were trying to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the response for the http-component is stored in the out-portion of the exchange. The reason why your file is empty is because it is writing the in-portion.

You could try something like this to copy the out-body to the in-portion:

```
.setBody(simple("${out.body}"))
.to("file://D:/tmp/restoutput");
```

I'm not used to writing routes in Java DSL but it should look something like that if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: How do I use this?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally got it to work with the help of all the answers. Shown below is the final working code.

1. Using Routes-

   ```
   from("timer://simpleTimer?repeatCount=1")
       .to("http://localhost:8089/mock/success")
       .process(exchange -> {
             String response = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
             exchange.getOut().setBody(msg);
        })
       .to("file://D:/tmp/?fileName=restoutput"); // This was missing earlier
   ```
2. Using ProducerTemplate-

   ```
   ProducerTemplate template = new DefaultCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
   Exchange exchange = template.request("http://localhost:8089/mock/success", exchangeObjcet -> {});
   String response = exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class)
   ```

The second one doesn't write it to file though. It can be done easily by using the standard file api of java.

Comment: I still don't undersatnd why you set the out exchange. You can use the in exchange through your lifecycle.

Comment: I guess because I'm a noob! Thanks for the tip @SoucianceEqdamRashti